# Cordova push notification android and ios using FCM

Tags: cordova

I am new for Cordova, is anyone worked on push notification for Cordova hybrid application. please suggest me the push notification plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cordova-plugin-firebase is a good plugin for cordova firebase implementation.
I worked on this plugin. This plugin brings push notifications, analytics, event tracking, crash reporting and more from Google Firebase to your Cordova project! Android and iOS supported.

**Supported Cordova Versions**

```
cordova: >= 6
cordova-android: >= 6.4
cordova-ios: >= 4
```

**Installation**

Install the plugin by adding it to your project's config.xml:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.0.0" />
```

or by running:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save
```

**Setup**

Download your Firebase configuration files, GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS and google-services.json for android, and place them in the root folder of your cordova project. Check out this firebase article for details on how to download the files.

```
- My Project/
    platforms/
    plugins/
    www/
    config.xml
    google-services.json       <--
    GoogleService-Info.plist   <--
```

Answer (score 0):

mobile push notifications using pubnub

APNS and GCM/FCM push notifications combined with realtime messaging for maximum user engagement

https://www.pubnub.com/products/mobile-push-notifications/

Easily and reliably automate and send APNS and/or FCM notifications as either a primary communication option, or as a fall-back using PubNub Realtime Messaging. PubNub ensures your push notifications are cross-platform, cross-device, and secure end-to-end with powerful TLS and AES encryption.